# Why do I have to add an unused variable in my mod rewrite url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I have this code for my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3
```

It works fine however when I print out the get array on index.php it ignores the first variable so i have to do something like `spareslist.com/randomthing/page/var1/var2`

How would I be able to use this without having to have a random variable before the others?

Answer (score 1):

What about using the ^ in RewriteRule? Like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3
```

Comment: If rule is placed in .htaccess then URL will have no leading slash when matching in RewriteRule pattern.

Comment: Yes, that could be the reason of his mistake! But he should also involve ^ character as I said. I editted my code to reflect your comment.